# BottomSheetDialogFragment inside Fragment problem

Tags: android-fragments, dialog, bottom-sheet

After showing BottomSheetDialogFragment inside Fragment and interacting with specific buttons like increasing price as per below photo, the Fragment disappear and showing as per second photo.

code:

```
increase_price.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String coun_cost = shipment_price.getText().toString();

            if (coun_cost.isEmpty()) {
                counter_price = 0;
                counter_price = counter_price + 5;
                requestFocus(shipment_price);
                shipment_price.setText(String.valueOf(counter_price));
            } else {
                counter_price = Integer.valueOf(coun_cost);
                counter_price = counter_price + 5;
                requestFocus(shipment_price);
                shipment_price.setText(String.valueOf(counter_price));
            }
        }
    });

    decrement_price.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String coun_cost = shipment_price.getText().toString();

            if (!coun_cost.isEmpty()) {
                counter_price = Integer.valueOf(coun_cost);
                counter_price = counter_price - 5;
                if (counter_price >= 0) {
                    requestFocus(shipment_price);
                    shipment_price.setText(String.valueOf(counter_price));
                } else {
                    counter_price = 0;
                    requestFocus(shipment_price);
                    shipment_price.setText(String.valueOf(counter_price));
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: show us your code.

Comment: @JohnJoe code added.

Comment: can you show the whole fragment class,I am dont think there is any error in above code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem after removing below lines of code.

```
    param = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getWindow().getAttributes();
    param.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    param.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.DIM_AMOUNT_CHANGED;
```